# How to put new udev rules for network interfaces into effect without rebooting?

Tags: networking, interface, udev

Om my Raspberry, I have two USB-Ethernet-Adapters connected to two USB ports. These would show up als `eth1` and `eth2`.

In order to have a well-defined eth device name for each of them, based on the USB port position where it is plugged into, I created these 2 udev rules (note that the attribute `devnum` contains the USB port number on the Raspberry USB switch):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1a02", ATTRS{devnum}=="4", NAME="eth-special0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1a02", ATTRS{devnum}=="5", NAME="eth-special1"
```

This works - after rebooting, instead of `eth1` and `eth2`, two interfaces `eth-special0` and `eth-special1` are present. Everything fine.

My question: how can I put these "networking udev rules" into effect *without* having to reboot the whole system?

What I tried to no avail:

- `udevadm trigger`
- `udevadm trigger --action="change"`

These retrigger mechanism work in general with new udev rules, but seemingly not necessarily for network devices. These seem to be "stickier" than others.

So is there a way to activate these rules without rebooting - even better: without even restarting the entire networking service?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:
`udevadm control --reload-rules`.

In my yocto-base Linux distribution if I modify a rule about USB storage plug in (sorry not about *network changes* like in your question) and execute `udevadm control --reload-rules` the rule change doesn't need a reboot.

You can find info about `control --reload-rules` [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm).

Comment: I tried this as well - but for new network devices this would also have no effect. Still a reboot is needed.